# H2O equivalent of allStringVecToCategorical() and score() api in H2O python

Tags: h2o

I am using `H2O GLRM` model in my scala code.
Now migrating scala code to python.

However I am not able to find following equivalent methods in H2O python module

1) `allStringVecToCategorical()` [Belongs to H2OFrameSupport Trait]

*Using the api as follow in the code:*

```
withLockAndUpdate(h2OFrameForImputation) 
  {
      allStringVecToCategorical(_)
  }
```

2) public Frame `score(Frame fr)` [Belongs to `hex.Model`]

*Using the api as follow in the code:*

```
glrmModel.score(h2OFrameForImputation)
```

Please let me know the equivalent method in `H2O` python module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent python api function for `allStringVecToCategorical(_)`, the closest is `.asfactor()` (docs [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight=asfactor#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.asfactor)) which you can use to convert a single column to type enum/categorical. To get the subset of columns with type string you can use the method `columns_by_type()` (docs [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight=columns#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.columns_by_type)).

For `.score()` you can use the python api's `.predict()` method (docs [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?highlight=predict#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.predict)).

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you Lauren it works for me and quick reply